# item on hold background color and text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am looking for a way to the change background color and text color when holding on an item

Example:
[image]

I found a way to change the text color however i cannot find a way to change the background color

Comment: can you add the xml to check the used components?

Comment: why dont you use longpress ClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

You can using selectors:

1) add files to  src/main/res/drawable
button_accent.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rect_rounded_accentdark"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rect_rounded_accent" />
</selector>
```

rect_rounded_accent.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

rect_rounded_accentdark.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorAccentDark"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

2) use button_accent.xml as backgroud view
for example:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/enter"
android:text="@string/authorize"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textSize="14dp"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/button_accent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="43dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change your button's background color to to red for example then:

```
//declaring  a button
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //initializing the button
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
    LongButoonClick();
}

public void LongButoonClick(){
   //initializing a long Clicklistener for the button
   button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    //here we will change the button color to red
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    return false;
                }
            }
    );
}
```